# Pandas DataFrame concatenate along new axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a directory with 1000+ csv files, which I want to read in and store in a dataframe, to then save that to a file. I would like the dataframe dimensions to be [file, line in file, content of line]. This is what I have come up with so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

csv_files = glob.glob("data/*sample.csv")
df = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_files)
dataset = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```

This gives me a dataframe with the shape [line, content of line] but I can no longer see which file the line is from. Can somebody help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You can create list of all filenames withour extension in list and then pass to parameter `keys` in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), so `MultiIndex` is created. Last remove second level and convert it to index:

```
from os.path import splitext, basename

csv_files = glob.glob("data/*sample.csv")
names = (splitext(basename(x))[0] for x in csv_files)
dfs = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_files)

df = (pd.concat(dfs, keys=names)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .rename_axis('New')
        .reset_index())
```

Comment: This still only gives me 2 axes, the first axis are all lines concatenated from all files :/

Comment: I want the first axis to tell me the file, second to tell me the line in the file, and the third to be the content of the line

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more long-winded that jezrael's solution, but this is what I've used for ages. It's probably time to make it more concise though.

```
os.chdir('C:/')
file_list = []
for file in os.listdir():
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df['Filename'] = file
    file_list.append(df)
    df = pd.concat(file_list, ignore_index=True)
```